# How to remove old client keys in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I am trying to install puppet 6 on the agents and add them to the new puppet 6 master. As a part of this task, I a need to remove old client keys on the agent nodes: `find /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ -type f | xargs rm` but that throws an error so obviously I am not sure how to use this command correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You better use

```
salt-key -d <machine-name>
```